# Динамическое выделение памяти для массива внутри функции.Из- за ошибки инициализации в строке if (numbers[i]) выходной массив остаётся пустым

Tags: c++

Задание:реализовать функцию, формирующую
выходной массив нечетных чисел B на
основе входного целочисленного
массива A такой, что каждый элемент
выходного массива

- получен путем суммирования
  наиближайших элементов входного
  массива для получения нечетного
  числа.
- равен элементу в той же позиции
  входного массива, если он нечетный
  Глобальные параметры использовать запрещено;
  допустимо использование дополнительных функций. Использовать только
  динамические массивы, ввод и вывод данных должен быть осуществлен в
  текстовый файл. Во входном и выходном файле необходимо указать
  размерность массива (массивов), размерность выходного массива
  определяется реализуемой функцией и является возвращаемым значением.
  Вход:
  9-
  3,11,3,6,
  7,6,7,9,3 ;
  Выход
  3-
  11,7,3 ;
  3 и 9 размеры массивов.
  Мой код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include<fstream>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

bool checkPrime(int number)

{
    if (number <= 1) {
        return false;
    }
    for (int i = 2; i * i <= number; i++) {
        if (number % i == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}


int main()
{
    

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");
    int size;
    cout << "Введите длинну массива:" << endl;
    cin >> size;
    int* numbers = new int[size];
    char ch;
    int count = 0;

    ifstream f("text.TXT");
    while (!(f.fail() || f.eof()) && count < size)
    {
        f >> numbers[count++];
        f >> ch;
    }
    int isprime = 0;
    int prime_counter = 0;
    int every_second_prime_size = 0;
    int Size = 100;

    cout << "\n Исходный массив: \n";
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        cout << numbers[i] << ' ';
    }

    f.close();
    int n = sizeof(*numbers) / sizeof(numbers[0]);
    int* every_second_prime = new int[Size];



    cout << "\n Получившийся массив: \n";

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
    {

        if (checkPrime(numbers[i])) здесь выходит предупреждение и написано массив не инициализирован.

        {
            prime_counter++;
            if (prime_counter % 2 == 0) {
                every_second_prime[every_second_prime_size++] = numbers[i];
            }
        }

    }

    for (int i = 0; i < every_second_prime_size++; i++)
    {
        cout << every_second_prime[i] << ' ';

    }
    return 0;


    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {

        ofstream file("text1.TXT", ios_base::app);
        if (file.is_open()) {

            file << every_second_prime[i] << " ";
        }
        else
            cout << "Файл не найден!" << endl;
    }


}
```

И из- за ошибки инициализации в строке if (numbers[i]) выходной массив остаётся пустым

Answer (score 0):

```cpp
int n = sizeof(*numbers) / sizeof(numbers[0]);
```

Здесь точно что-то не то: `*numbers` равен `numbers[0]`, а значит результат равен `1`, независимо от вашего массива.